Converting array of hashtables back and forth with JSON in Powershell 5.1
I have an array of hashtables $a (I give a very simplyfied example):
$a = @()
$a += @{id=1; name='Aron' }
$a += @{id=2; name='Benny'}
$a

Result:
Name                           Value
----                           -----
id                             1
name                           Aron
id                             2
name                           Benny

I try to serialize and then deserialize it, using the json fonctionality in Powershell 5.1:
$b = $a | ConvertTo-Json | ConvertFrom-Json

but the two objects are not the same, which is the goal.
$b

Result:
id name
-- ----
 1 Aron
 2 Benny

The types are the same:
$a.getType()
$b.getType()

Result:
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

I've tried all kind of combinations of getEnumerator() and out-string, with no succes.
What to do to use jSON conversion back and forth, and get the same array of hashtables in the end?
The reason I need this: the JSON conversion should save the serialized array in a file and be able to fetch it and deserialize it later.

There's no immediate solution to this problem in 5.1 - ConvertFrom-Json always deserializes objects to a psobject, not a hashtable. Either use a newer version of PowerShell, or use a 3rd party JSON serializer

They are indeed both arrays but the difference is the types they contain (e.g. $a[0].GetType()) which in fact defines the display output. This ConvertTo-Expression -Explicit might help to get a grip on the object graph and the embedded types or use the ObjectGraphTools to do other things along with writing to a .psd1 PowerShell data file (Export-Expression) instead or converting the (mapping) nodes with Copy-ObjectGraph.

In PowerShell 7+ the solution is to use ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable. For PowerShell 5.1, the alternative is to use the JavaScrtiptSerializer Class to deserialize your Json string, this will get you an array of Dictionary`2 objects.
$jsonstring = @'
[
  {
    "name": "Aron",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Benny",
    "id": 2
  }
]
'@

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web.Extensions
$serializer = [Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer]::new()
$json = $serializer.Deserialize($jsonstring, [object])

If you specifically want an array of hashtables, you could do:
$json = $serializer.Deserialize($jsonstring, [hashtable[]])

Problem with this approach is that the Json string must be an array otherwise it would fail:
$serializer.Deserialize('{ "id": 1, "name": "Aron" }', [hashtable[]])
# Errors with:
# No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'System.Collections.Hashtable[]'

And a way to handle the deserialization to hashtable if you're not sure what Json you're getting could be:
$outputType = [hashtable[]]
if ($jsonstring -match '^\s*\{') {
    $outputType = [hashtable]
}

$serializer.Deserialize($jsonstring, $outputType)


You could also do $serializer.Deserialize($jsonstring, [hashtable]) if the root value is an object - that way the outermost dictionary actually becomes a hashtable :)
